# Pragmatic or theoretic approach towards designing something (mainly logo/branding)?

Tags: logo, branding, freelance, type-theory

**So basically,**

I've been studying graphic design or design of visual communication for 4 years and now entering my final year. I've been studying all the elements such as illustration, photography, cinematography, and all that. Also been reading and taught about the theory regarding this field, like semiotics, gestalt, visual hierarchy and all that.

All that knowledge and skills that i've required over the couple of years i've been studying design is very good to have. But when it came to designing in real life (like freelancing or somekind) i'm stumbling upon a dilemma, because  i find it easier to use my instinct or intuition perhaps to design something rather than using all these theories. Finding it easier to use intuition also makes me worried am i doing it wrong? what if my design (a logo in this case) doesn't conform to the theories and rules and so i've made a badly design logo. So i went from being very confident to worried and just stop doing it all together and start binging all those youtube videos on design.

How is your approach on designing a logo (or any)? i'm a really really confused and a bit desperate at this point. And sorry for the long backstory

Thank you,

Comment: There are **no** rules regarding conceptualization and ideation.

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatic.

All that school theory, the youtube videos and whatever jobs you are given, all add up to your experience, which is what real life freelancing is about: turning your accumulated experience into deliverables that work.

Then, in real life, anything works: while you were studying the theory of design and communication, other people were just buying 10$ logo templates and selling them for much more. Equally important is dealing with clients and people in general, knowing what to say and when to say it. Real life experience!